# Как запретить пользователю вводить в QLineEdit что-либо кроме URL?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, form, url

Как запретить пользователю вводить в `QLineEdit` что-либо кроме URL?

Ситуация: нужна форма (необязательно `QLineEdit`, но я не нашёл специальной формы для ссылок), которая не даст пользователю ввести что-либо кроме ссылок. Видел формы, которые разрешают только ввод чисел, а не букв. Нужно что-то типа такого, только для ссылок. При этом при проверке не обязательно подключение к интернету. Знаю про класс `QUrl`, но его метод isValid() пропускает и нерабочие URL почему-то.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под нерабочими URL?

Comment: @maestro Рабочие -- с правильным синтаксисом. Но они могут вести на несуществующую страницу, например

Comment: Правильный синтаксис - это синтаксис, соответствующий RFC 3986, и метод `isValid` проверяет URL на соответствие этому стандарту. Приведите примеры нерабочих URL, которые пропускает метод `isValid`.

Comment: то есть что бы начиналась как ссылка и имела в начале https://?

Comment: @jNX, кроме https если и куча других: http, ftp, file, и т.п. :)

Comment: В чем проблема тогда заключается ? Самому распарсить строчку посимвольно и проверить на совпадение ? Не совпадает с одним из нужных очищаем поле

Comment: Без подключения к интернету никак не проверить - рабочий URL или нет. Можно только проверить соответствие синтаксиса стандарту.

Answer (score 3):

Проверка по ходу ввода делается с помощью подклассов [`QValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html), можно сделать свой на основе `QUrl`, а можно просто взять [`QRegExpValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html) из коробки и регулярку <s>из гугла</s> [с en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)<sup>*</sup>:

```
QLineEdit *leUrl= new QLineEdit(this);
QRegExp urlRx{"https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{2,256}\\.[a-z]{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)"};
leUrl->setValidator(QRegExpValidator(urlRx));
```

---

<sup>* Не забывая удвоить обратные слеши, дабы компилятор С++ сам не пытался их интерпретировать.</sup>